# Writing Visual Studio Add-Ins in C++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

Would you consider it a reasonable idea to implement a Visual Studio 2010 add-in in C++ because it's the language you know best/that's normally used in-house/that gives you the full power to do even rare things? Today C++ seems quite unpopular in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT writing Visual Studio add-ins in C++ means dealing with COM, at that is cumbersome in C++. I, for one, would avoid writing add-ins in C++ for this reason alone.